# jQuery countdown hide days/hours/minutes if none left

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I'm using The Final Countdown jQuery script.. http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

I want to hide days, minutes etc if there is none left (ie, reach 0).

At this moment it will display something like..

00 Days 00 Hours 13 Minutes 58 Seconds

I want to display it like..

13 Minutes 58 Seconds

**HTML**

```
<span id="clock-{{ $game->id }}"></span>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var endGame = moment.tz("{{ $game->updated_at->addDays(3) }}", "Europe/Volgograd");

                $('#clock-{{ $game->id }}').countdown(endGame.toDate(), function(event) {
                    $(this).html(event.strftime('%-D days %-H hours %-M min %-S sec')).on('finish.countdown', function(event){
                        $(this).html(event.strftime('This Game has Ended.'));
                        $('.clock-{{ $game->id }}').fadeOut(2000);
                    });
                });
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can put a few conditions for achieving this.

```
var endGame = moment.tz("{{ $game->updated_at->addDays(3) }}", "Europe/Volgograd");

$('#clock-{{ $game->id }}').countdown(endGame.toDate(), function(event) {
   var str = "";
   // if 0 number of days, show H:M:S
   if(parseInt(event.strftime('%D')) == 0) {
       str = event.strftime('%-H hours %-M min %-S sec');
       // if 0 days 0 hours, show M:S
       if(parseInt(event.strftime('%H')) == 0) {
          str = event.strftime('%-M min %-S sec');
          // if 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes, show only Seconds
          if(parseInt(event.strftime('%M')) == 0) {
             str = event.strftime('%-S sec');
          }
       }
   } else {
       str = event.strftime('%-D days %-H hours %-M min %-S sec');
   }
   $(this).html(str).on('finish.countdown', function(event){
      $(this).html(event.strftime('This Game has Ended.'));
      $('.clock-{{ $game->id }}').fadeOut(2000);
   });
});
```

I don't know if the plugin provides some inbuilt feature for doing this so I took this approach.